# Can i add addValueEventListener inside onBindViewHolder while using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm newby with Android development. I started an app but got stuck with the following :

[image]

I would like to show the cart items and for every item i would like to get its infos from the product tree. In the code, prod is always null.

```
private void ShowCartItems()
{
    final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart List");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Cart> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Cart>()
                    .setQuery(cartListRef.child("User View")
                            .child(Prevalent.currentOnlineUser.getPhone())
                            .child("Products"), Cart.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder> adapter
            = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Cart, CartViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder holder, int i, @NonNull final Cart model)
        {

            DatabaseReference productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products").child(model.getPid());
            productsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onDataChange: ");
                    prod = dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Where are you using `prod`? Most likely you're using it before the `prod = dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class);` line has executed.

Comment: when i use the debbugger the line prod = dataSnapshot.getValue(Products.class); never get executed.

even if i try to access prod inside the OnDataChange like :

                      holder.txtProductName.setText(prod.getPname());
                        holder.txtProductPrice.setText("Price " + prod.getPrice());

Comment: Just to start : Is there any restriction on using addValueEventListener inside OnBindViewHolder ?

Comment: No there isn't. That's why I asked where you're using `prod`. But it sounds like this log `Log.d("TAG", "onDataChange: ");` doesn't even get written. In which case you should first implement minimal error handling, like this `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: prod was declared private into the class ... it worked when i declared it into the onDatachagne itself.
thanks!